# How to get the HTML result of a JMeter HTTPSampler call, using the API?

Tags: jmeter

In the JMeter GUI, we get the HTML result of an HTTP call by adding a "View Results Tree" to the HTTP Request, and then checking its Response Data field.

How do I accomplish this using the API?

Assume that I have the "classic" setup:

```
    StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("jmeter.properties");

    HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
    httpSampler.setProtocol( protocol );
    httpSampler.setDomain( domain );
    httpSampler.setPath( path );

    LoopController loopCtrl = new LoopController();
    loopCtrl.setLoops(1);
    loopCtrl.addTestElement(httpSampler);
    loopCtrl.setFirst(true);

    SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopCtrl);

    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("HTTP test plan");

    HashTree testTree = new HashTree();
    testTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
    testTree.add("loopCtrl", loopCtrl);
    testTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
    testTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);

    jm.configure(testTree);
    jm.run();
```

I am trying to achieve this by using HTTPSampleResult, but I haven't been able to inject it yet. Is this the right approach?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396194/how-to-generate-response-times-graph-from-jmeter-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

First of all add corresponding logic to save your test execution result into .jtl file

```
//add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
// summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}


// Store execution results into a .jtl file
String logFile = jmeterHome + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "example.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
testPlanTree.add(hashTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

Second: configure JMeter to save all the response data. It can be done via *user.properties* file which is located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation. Add the next lines to the file.

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

Once test run completes you should be able to open "example.jtl" file with View Results Tree listener and inspect request and response details.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about different JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.

Remember that storing full request and response details into .jtl file as well as using xml format for it causes overhead in CPU and RAM consumption so make sure that you use it for debugging purposes only so once you're happy with your test script revert changes in the user.properties file.

Also you can refer https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/ to see how to create JMeter-compliant script (so you should be able to open generated .jmx file via JMeter GUI) programmatically.